# Keep subplot in square while having (1,3) tiledlayout

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to show 3 images in a row while keeping them in original axes ratio (square). Using  methods like `tiledlayout (1,3)` or `subplot(1,3,1)` will make the individual image having different axes ratio. How can I fix this?

```
t=tiledlayout(1,3);
nexttile
imagesc(emap);colorbar
nexttile
imagesc(smap);colorbar
nexttile
imagesc(data)
```

If i set `tiledlayout('flow')`. It will show them not in a row which is not what I want.

[image]

Comment: Use `axis equal` after each plot.